# Is there a way to read through a string and convert each letter in the string to an item within another string?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string of letters: 
    x = "ABCDE"

And I have a string containing another set of letters:
    y = "VWXYZ"

The idea which I have been trying to solve is to take the original string x, and read all instances of the first letter ("V") from the second sting y into the first position of x. And then repeat this for all positions of x with all letters of y.

Have tried a few different loops but am having a hard time getting this correct.

```
for i in range(len(x)):
  print (x[i])
  replaced = False

  for z in range(len(y)):
    x.replace(x[0],y[0])
```

The input strings:

```
x = "ABCDE"
y = "VWXYZ"
```

Ideally the results would be printed with each sequence on a new line.
Desired Result:

```
"ABCDE" # starting sequence
"VBCDE" # replace first position in x with first position in y
"WBCDE" # replace first position in x with second position in y
"XBCDE" # replace first position in x with third position in y
"YBCDE" 
"ZBCDE" # replace first position in x with fifth position in y
"AVCDE" # replace second position in x with first position in y
"AWCDE" # replace second position in x with second position in y
.......
"ABCDZ" # This would be the final sequence in the series.
```

So basically I'm looking to produce strings of altered sequences with each string on a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `x.replace`, it will not modify the string in-place, it will return the modified string (and it will replace all instances, not just the one you wish to replace), you can use list-slicing and string-concatenation for this:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in y:
        print(x[:i] + j + x[i + 1:])
```

Output:

```
VBCDE
WBCDE
XBCDE
YBCDE
ZBCDE
AVCDE
AWCDE
AXCDE
AYCDE
AZCDE
ABVDE
ABWDE
ABXDE
ABYDE
ABZDE
ABCVE
ABCWE
ABCXE
ABCYE
ABCZE
ABCDV
ABCDW
ABCDX
ABCDY
ABCDZ
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "ABCDE"
y = "VWXYZ"
for i, _ in enumerate(x):
    for c in y:
        print(x[:i] + c + x[i + 1 :])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with x.replace ....

```
x = "ABCDE"
y = "VWXYZ"

for i in range(0, len(x)):
   for j in range(0, len(y)):
      print(x.replace(x[i],y[j]))

print("Original: " + x) # x is still same
```